# Android microphone input usb-c probem

Tags: android, audio, usb, microphone

i'd need some help... I'm using Android to build a simple audio level meter; i'm first using some app on store to have an idea on the performance of internal/external microphone. I see on my device that the spectrum results low-pass filtered about over 8KHz; same happens if i use an external USB adapter (a realtek usb audio card) with a dytonaudio microphone, that have a flat band over 20-20khz. It seems android digitally filters microphone input indipendentely from the source (analog plug or digital usb type-c source).

I see that there are any low-pass attenuation on other friend's phones.
I used the same app in every device i tested (DecibelX), in order to check as fast as possible.

What i can do to disable this sort of processing? I don't know if app use UNPROCESSED or MIC input type on AudioRecord class, but i can't understand why Android process by software the audiostream from USB-C audio card.

Can someone help me? excuse for my english....

Comment: Are you trying to write an app or use one?  If you're writing one, come back with a programming question about it.  We have no idea what's going on when you're using some random app we don't have source code for from the play store.

Comment: you'r right, but my question was related on Android backend audio system...i would now why same app behave differently on different phones. I've just built an app to process audio but i'm not sure if audio stream i receive is processed or not. 
my next step will be to save audio stream and process offline on my PC to see if there are any filtering. Do you have any graphic gui to plot a curve? i can calculate FFT but have some problem to plot on activity.